# Managing Selenium Tests

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, automation, automated-tests

We're looking at creating Selenium tests to help automate some of our testing.

Is there a tool/service/etc. for helping to manage those tests. Specifically, is there any kind of tool that helps keep them organized and documented?

If there isn't anything automated, are there any resources out there to help with this?

Ideally we'd like our testers to do the bulk of the work when it comes to these tests. Most of our testers have no programming background, so anything too intensive would be handled by the developers.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Diving in to stuff myself, I agree. Looking at adding Cucumber on top, but it will still require some coding it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Generally for setting up automation framework a good rule of thumb is to use what your developers are using for unit and integration testing. Following the same model eliminates the need to maintain/learn multiple tools, plus developers will be happier helping with those tests if they are in their normal environment.

To begin with, you will need 4 components:

- Source control (SVN, Git, etc.) for storing the source code of the tests. Some companies may not want the test code to be in the same repository as production code, so they may setup a separate server.
- A project (or projects), that contain the test code. Starting from the typical bare-bone development project, adding selenium libraries/dependencies to it will give a good starting point.
- Then you need an IDE to develop the tests. Again, ask developers what do they use.
- And finally you need something that executes those tests on schedule or on single button click. This is where development's CI product (e.g. Jenkins, Bamboo or whatever they are using) can be useful. This tool will not only run tests for you, but will also give a fairly well-organized results report and history. And it can deploy, say, latest build, or reset test environment.

But to achieve all this, I think you need to accept that testers will deal with writing and debugging the code. And test code has to be of good quality, so you would have to hire or develop 1-2 good automation developers in your team. Or have some developers committed to creation of the tests, which testers will only draft with Selenium IDE.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm actually the lead developer for my team. I'm diving in to Selenium and Cucumber a bit myself for the first time. I'm seeing there are some standards, but it is also a bit open as well. Also seeing that our testers will have to write some level of code as well.